# Is there any messaging software (or hardware) to work both synchronous and asynchronous?

Tags: load-balancing, synchronization

I need a messaging service to be a broker between my clients and my servers, which fulfill this requirements:

1. work with clients synchronously
2. send their requests to, and get their answers from servers asynchronously (just like sending the request as a message and giving the answer as another message.)
3. So it should memorize the request IDs to know send the answers to which client.
4. load-balancing between servers, while sending requests to them,

Is there any SW/HW for that? I prefer open source software.

Answer (score 1):

You could use RabbitMQ with a [Topic Exchange](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html) where the routing is done based on the consumer tag, or other message variable.

You don't want the "queue to memorize the request id", that's all part of the logic of your application's consumer / publisher.

The broker is just that, a broker, and the queue should just be a queue.  The really clever stuff happens in your usage of the queue.